# Angularjs копия dom после компиляции

Tags: angularjs, dom, компиляция

Разрабатываю первое приложение на AngularJS. В приложении имеется блок (назовем его "container") с дочерними элементами("page"),в которых создаются поддочерние элементы("ui") пользователем. К ui применяются директивы ng-style, иногда выражения, например:

```html
<div class="container" main-container> 
   <div id="pagec0d4">
       <div class="ui" ng-style="{'backgroundColor': txt6784}" name="Label">{{txt6784}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Выполняем $compile(container)($scope) и получаем нужный результат, НО уже невозможно вернуть выражение {{txt6784}} в прежний вид.

Задача в том, чтобы сохранять режим, где container c не примененными директивами и выражениями и откомпилированными и переключаться между ними. Размещать копию container не желательно(у элементов уникальные id).

Какими средствами angular пользоваться, роутинг или что другое?

Comment: Если честно - вообще ничего не понятно. Что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: После применения $compile выражение {{txt6784}} уже представляется в виде значения. Могу ли я обратно вернуть выражение {{txt6784}} без манипуляций вроде сохранения копии container?

Comment: Я думаю нет, стандартными средствами вы этого не сможете сделать. А зачем вам это надо?

Comment: Мне необходимо использовать "container" в режиме а-ля рантайм. Применили $compile, а значение переменной "txt6784" получаем с бэкенда через сокет. Плюс ко всему, создаются для "txt6784" наблюдатели. А вот реализовать обратный процесс - удаление наблюдателей и возврат {{txt6784}} пока не понятен.

Comment: Понятно, как вы это используете. Совсем не понятно, зачем вам надо обратный процесс делать? Для чего?

Comment: Ну, например, мне нужно будет добавить другие дочерние элементы в "container", в выражении {{txt6784}} использовать другую переменную и т.п.

Comment: Извините, ничем не могу помочь. Потому что все еще до конца не понятен *use cases*. Возможно, вы выбрали не тот инструмент. Для динамической генерации шаблона все же больше подходит `jQuery`, например. Ангулар все же заточен на статические шаблоны.